# Reverse Conduction/Third Quadrant operation of SiC MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, inverter, sic, losses

Good Day,
I have to calculate the Conduction losses of SiC MOSFET and how I am calculating total losses is by segregating the losses into three categoriesincludes, Forward Conduction loss of MOSFET, Reverse Conduction Loss of MOSFET and Body Diode Reverse Conduction Losses. I am unable to understand the phenomenon of reverse conduction operation of MOSFET. Can anyone please explain or refer some good literature considering me as an beginner with very basic knowledge.
Thanks

Comment: What specifically is it that you don't understand? Is it at a physical level or a data sheet level or what? Do you understand the forward conduction? Do you understand that reverse conduction of the MOSFET is in parallel with the body diode?

Comment: I want to understand the behaviour of SiC Mosfet during reverse conduction to compute the losses that will occur during its reverse conduction. Yes I do understand forward conduction of MOSFET